# Stack/Unstack Multi-index pivot table in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the follow Python Pandas Table:

[image]

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

[image]

How do I stack/unstack the "Peat-Forming" to have "PBL_AWI" and "Description" underneath?

Like this:

```
-Peat-Forming      
    -PBL_AWI       Values...
    -Description   Values...
```

Comment: Is this just a formatting thing?  If you need finer control over how the output looks you can use https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/ (which pandas uses saving to xlsx) to manually specify an output layout, although it will obviously be a lot more code.  Or you can do something similar for HTML.

Comment: @chrisb Maybe, I can try playing around on the Excel side to get what I want. Do you happen to know off the cuff how to get sub-totals for the Non-Peatlands and Peatlands? Was thinking of spilting the tables (b = p_table.loc['Non-Peatlands']) Add an Total row and then append both tables back together. Hopefully having an overall total as well. I realize this is outside scope of my question, just I just post new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unstacking would create another level in the columns level it would make it wide.  Looking into xlsxwriter is something I recommend but you could probably try using this. (Kind of hacky though)

```
writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
non_peatlands = df.loc['Non-Peatlands']
peat = df.loc['Peatlands']

peat.reset_index().to_excel(writer,'1',startrow=no_peatlands.shape[0])#not sure if you need to add +1 or -1 to start or not so header is overwritten play around with it
no_peatlands.reset_index().to_excel(writer,'1') #this comes second to overwrite the columns of peat frame
writer.save()
```

For the totals you. calculate and append to dataframes peat and non_peatlands.  You might have to play around with the MultiIndex to get it to merge. eg `peat.index = pd.MultiIndex('set the correct index probably should use from tuples')`  tuple of the Total peatlands looks like this `("Total Peatlands","")`  to get the cells to merge properly.

As you can see my answer is pretty hacky (but possible) with just the pandas implementation.  I would recommend using xlsxwriter like @user765015 said